# Eigenstates of large system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

How does one calculate the eigenvalues of a unitary 3 by 3 block circulant matrix where 
$$U = -\frac{i}{3} \begin{pmatrix}
    \Lambda_{1} & \Lambda_{2} & \Lambda_{3} \\
    \Lambda_{3} & \Lambda_{1} & \Lambda_{2} \\
    \Lambda_{2} & \Lambda_{3} & \Lambda_{1} \end{pmatrix}$$
where 
$$ \Lambda_{1}  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & -2\sqrt{2} \\ -2\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \Lambda_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -2\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} 
    , \Lambda_{3}  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

$\Lambda_{2}$ and $\Lambda_{3}$ essentially contain Number operators when you boil it down. Ive done techniques from a Lin Alg book to represent the matrix as a sum of tensor products and diagonalize everything however due to the 12 by 12 nature of the matrix it makes it very difficult to find an analytic solution

Comment: If there is some common eigenspace $V$ of the $\Lambda_i$ you can treat them as scalars and work in $V^3$.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: That would be done by finding eigenvectors of the $\Lambda_i$ individually and seeing if there is any coincidences among those. Say a vector $v \in \mathbb{C}^4$ where $\Lambda_i v = \lambda_i v$. Then restricting to the $\mathbb{C}^3 \subset \mathbb{C}^{12}$. But that requires a coincidence that upon second glance doesn't seem to happen in this case.